# No puedo meter un svg con la propiedad innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, svg

Estoy intentado meter un `svg` dentro de un `span` pero no he podido

El `svg` es este

```
<svg width='22px' height='24px' viewBox='0 0 20 22' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'><g id='Elementos' stroke='none' stroke-width='1.2' fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'><g id='home' transform='translate(1.000000, 1.000000)' stroke='#0d0334'><path d='M0,7 L9,0 L18,7 L18,18 C18,19.1045695 17.1045695,20 16,20 L2,20 C0.8954305,20 0,19.1045695 0,18 L0,7 Z' id='Shape'></path><polyline id='Shape' points='6 20 6 10 12 10 12 20'></polyline></g></g></svg>
```

Funciona, de hecho si lo agrego como HTML al template si lo pinta, el problema es que ese SVG viene desde una api, y viene así como lo puse intenté lo siguiente

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of items">
   <span [innerHTML]="item.svg"><span>
   {{ item.name }}
 </li>
</ul>
```

Un ejemplo de qué trae adentro `items` es:

```
items: any = [{
  name: 'home',
  svg: "<svg width='22px' height='24px' viewBox='0 0 20 22' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'><g id='Elementos' stroke='none' stroke-width='1.2' fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'><g id='home' transform='translate(1.000000, 1.000000)' stroke='#0d0334'><path d='M0,7 L9,0 L18,7 L18,18 C18,19.1045695 17.1045695,20 16,20 L2,20 C0.8954305,20 0,19.1045695 0,18 L0,7 Z' id='Shape'></path><polyline id='Shape' points='6 20 6 10 12 10 12 20'></polyline></g></g></svg>"
}]
```

El nombre si aparece, pero el `svg` que funge como un icono no sale nada. aparece como un `span` vacío

Intenté usar `ViewEncapsulation`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio',
  templateUrl: './inicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inicio.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Sigue sin funcionar. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola @Alberto, prueba  definirlo así `<span>{{ item.svg }}<span>` en lugar de `<span [innerHTML]="item.svg"><span>`.

Comment: Gracias David, lo que recomiendas me hace render del texto del span

Answer (score 0):

Espero no sea muy tarde, pero la respuesta puede ayudar a futuros desarrolladores.

El problema es que angular no generará el svg porque lo bloquea por defecto, por cuestiones de seguridad. Lo que tienes que hacer es confiar en la fuente para poder hacer el render utilizando el `[innerHTML]`.

```
   /** En tu constructor importa DomSanitizer **/
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
     sanatizeItems();
   }

  /** itera tu arreglo y utiliza el metodo  **/
  sanatizeItems(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      this.items[i].svg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.items[i].svg);
    }
  }
```